# OpenCover for xUnit tests in .Net Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, opencover, test-coverage

I have 2 projects in my VS2017 .Net Core solution

- Application (dll)
- Application.Test (dll)

In the Application I have Service1.cs with class `Service1` and in Application.Test I have Service1.Test.cs with xUnit unit tests for `Service1`. In Application.Test.csproj file I have reference to Application like

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Application.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Service1.Test compiles and runs well - I don't have any problems with it.

How can I call OpenCover (and ReportGenerator if possible) to analyze and create results of test coverage of `Service1` by Service1.Test?

I tried to do like this:

```
dotnet.exe test "path to Application.Test"
```

But I had results where Service1.Test covered itself - looks like OpenCover didn't "see" Application project and Service1 class at all.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: I can't see how OpenCover is used here - OpenCover is not part of dotnet.exe but a separate tool. Please show all the steps. Also refer to the [wiki](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Usage)

Comment: I used dotnet.exe as "target" and "test "path to Application.Test"" as "targetarguments". Also I tried to use xunit.console as "target" and "Application.Test.dll" as "targetarguments" but had an error like "assembly has not available tests" or something like that (I can't clarify error now, sorry).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following items to the .csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Required for both Application.csproj file and Application.Test.csproj file.